# Dictionary merging

Tags: c#, dictionary, merge

I have a Dictionary of dictionaries :

```
SortedDictionary<int,SortedDictionary<string,List<string>>>
```

I would like to merge two dictionaries for example key = 2 and key = 3.

Very important I could have duplicate keys in the respective dictionaries.

example key = 2 has a dictionary Key,Value `"1000",{a,b,c}`
and key = 3 has a dictionary key,Value `"1000",{z}`.

So I would like to merge key 2 and key 3 and the result would be the following Sorted Dictionary key, Value `"1000",{a,b,c,z}`.

I am a beginner with LINQ syntax so could you help solve this with detail code..

Thanks

Comment: Based on cursory inspection, I'd say there's a very good change you're using the wrong data structure for your job. For a start, although you have "1000",{a,b,c,z} as your target value, you don't state what the target key should be. Additionally, pairing up each value to with each other value requires a linear search for each item in the value collection, making it at least O(n^2). By chance, could you describe what your problem does and what kind of data your dictionary represents? From there, someone might be able to suggest a better data structure which supports efficient merging.

Comment: It wouldn't be a linear search.  (It's a _Sorted_Dictionary)

Comment: I get suspicious when I see nested dictionaries. Have you thought of using a composite key such as `SortedDictionary<Tuple<int, string>, List<string>>`? What are you using this for? A different data structure might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a LINQ problem. Here's a generic version that will solve your problem.

```
static class SortedDictionaryExtensions {
    public static void MergeKeys<TKey1, TKey2, TValue>(
        this SortedDictionary<TKey1, SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>>> dictionary,
        TKey1 intoKey,
        TKey1 fromKey
    ) {
        if (dictionary == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        }
        if (intoKey == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("intoKey");
        }
        if (fromKey == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fromKey");
        }

        SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>> to;
        SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>> from;
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(intoKey, out to)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("intoKey");
        }
        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(fromKey, out from)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fromKey");
        }
        foreach(TKey2 key in from.Keys) {
            if (to.Keys.Contains(key)) {
                to[key].AddRange(from[key]);
            }
            else {
                to.Add(key, from[key]);
            }
        }
        dictionary.Remove(fromKey);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>> list = 
     new SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>>();
 list.Add(2, new SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>());
 list[2].Add("1000", new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
 list[2].Add("2000", new List<string>() { "b", "c" });
 list.Add(4, new SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>());
 list[4].Add("1000", new List<string>() { "z" });
 list[4].Add("3000", new List<string>() { "y" });

 list.MergeKeys(2, 4);
```

Here's how you approach a problem like this. First, specify what you're trying to do.

Given a `SortedDictionary<TKey1, SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>>>` and two keys `intoKey` and `fromKey` in the dictionary, merge the dictionary with key `fromKey` into the dictionary with key `intoKey`.

Now specify what it means to merge two dictionaries. Given two dictionaries `to` and `from` of type `SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>>` to merge them means the following. For each `TKey2 key` in `from` there are two possiblities:

1. `key` is in `to`. In this case add the list `from[key]` to the list `to[key]`.
2. `key` is not in `to`. In this case add `key` to `to` with value `from[key]`.

Then, remove key `fromKey` from the dictionary.

Let's translate this to code:

> Given a `SortedDictionary<TKey1, SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>>>` and two keys `intoKey` and `fromKey` in the dictionary

```
SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>> to;
SortedDictionary<TKey2, List<TValue>> from;
// check that dictionary has intoKey
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(intoKey, out to)) {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("intoKey");
}
// check that dictionary has fromKey
if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(fromKey, out from)) { 
     throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fromKey");
}
```

> For each `TKey2 key` in `from` there are two possiblities:

```
foreach(TKey2 key in from.Keys) {
     // key is in to
     if (to.Keys.Contains(key)) {
          // add the list from[key] to the list to[key]
          to[key].AddRange(from[key]); 
     }
     // key is not in to
     else { 
          // add an entry (key, from[key]) to the dictionary
          to.Add(key, from[key]); 
     }
 }
```

> Then, remove key `fromKey` from the dictionary.

```
dictionary.Remove(fromKey);
```

The rest of the code is just error checking

Comment: Thank you very much Jason
This is what I was trying to accomplish
Bernard

Answer (score 1):

LINQ will not help much here.

You should loop through each KeyValuePair in the second dictionary, call `TryGetValue` to find the corresponding sub-dictionary for the key in the first dictionary (if it's not there, add it), then repeat the process for the sub-dictionary, and finally, add all of the items in the list from the second dictionary to the corresponding list in the first dictionary.

You should be able to convert that to C# relatively easily; we will not write all of your code for you.